# Adding JPanels to JFrame one after another vertically, each touches the border horizontally

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe

I want to add JPanels to JFrame one after another vertically. Each panel should cover the whole width of jframe. These panels should cover the width even if the frame is re sized. I want to have this using any layout. Threads shouldn't be used. Grab the point from the included images what I want to have.
Thanks in advance. Any try of help will be greatly appreciated...

**Here is the code you requested and down voted me for...**

```
public class AttachToWalls extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JLabel m1;
    JLabel m2;
    JPanel pane;
    JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
    JScrollPane jsp;
    JButton sender = new JButton("Sender");
    JButton receiver = new JButton("Receiver");

    AttachToWalls() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jsp = new JScrollPane(pane);
        add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        sender.addActionListener(this);
        receiver.addActionListener(this);
        bottom.add(sender);
        bottom.add(receiver);
        add(bottom);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == sender) {
            m1 = new JLabel("Message from Sender...");
            remove(sender);
            remove(receiver);
            Component comp = Box.createHorizontalStrut(this.getWidth() - m1.getWidth());
            comp.setBackground(Color.red);
            JPanel pane1 = new JPanel();
            pane1.setBackground(Color.gray);
            pane1.add(m1);
            pane1.add(comp);
            add(pane1);
            this.validate();
        } else if (e.getSource() == receiver) {
            m2 = new JLabel("Messsage from Receiver...");
            Component comp = Box.createHorizontalStrut((int) this.getWidth() - m2.getWidth());
            comp.setBackground(Color.red);
            JPanel pane2 = new JPanel();
            pane2.setBackground(Color.gray);
            pane2.add(m2);
            pane2.add(comp);
            add(pane2);
            this.validate();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AttachToWalls();
    }
}
```

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to do this yourself? Do you have a runnable code sample you can share?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Come and see the code what I tried.

Comment: @Gorb Brother See my code.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're implementing this as an `ActionListener`. **What are you using this in**? You're also (I think) using both `BorderLayout` and adding `Box`-based struts to the container? Not sure that'll work at all.

Comment: @Gorb I want this for a chat application. My QUESTION is that I cannot do this and how to do this. You may do this OR give me my reputations back.

Comment: You want a `JFrame` with a `BoxLayout` that when a new chat message is received (presumably by a `Listener`) adds a single `JPanel` to your `JFrame`. Which would require rewriting what you've shown here, I think.

Comment: [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html), with a large width for the preferred size of the items.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks Brother. Yes I have tried it but the problem with BoxLayout is that the components are re sized automatically to cover the whole height but I want the height of jpanel fixed. `setLayout (new BoxLayout (this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));`

Comment: One could set the maximum size of the children. And then there is the GridLayout. And yes they did not change to JavaFX for nothing.

Comment: see my solution @  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26063065/1966247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After a lot of effort I have solved your problem, hope you will accept my solution :)**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class ChatPane extends JFrame {

    JPanel msg = null;
    JLabel sub = null;
    Box center = Box.createVerticalBox();
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(center);
    JPanel ctrl = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JButton send = new JButton("Send");
    JButton rec = new JButton("Recieve");

    public ChatPane() {
        ctrl.add(send);
        ctrl.add(rec);
        Container cnt = getContentPane();

        cnt.add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cnt.add(ctrl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                msg = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                msg.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3) );
                sub = new JLabel("Sender. . . . Message");
                sub.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
                msg.add(sub, BorderLayout.WEST);
                msg.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, (int)msg.getPreferredSize().getHeight()));
                center.add(msg);
                validate();
            }
        });
        rec.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                msg = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                msg.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3) );
                sub = new JLabel("Reciver. . . . Message");
                sub.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                msg.add(sub, BorderLayout.EAST);
                msg.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, (int)msg.getPreferredSize().getHeight()));
                center.add(msg);
                validate();
            }
        });
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChatPane();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `GridBagLayout`. It supports a "fill" constraint that allows you to fill the component in a grid. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information on the contraints you can use.

Or if you want to go outside the box you can use the [Relative Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/). It can work like the BoxLayout. It can display the components vertically at the preferred height, but it has a parameter to fill the width automatically. It is not part of the JDK but you don't have to worry about building constraints.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you cannot show more than once instance of a label or any component for that matter.

Instead of continuously adding your label in the action listener like this :

```
    pane1.setBackground(Color.gray); 
    pane1.add(m1);
```

Re-instantiate it like this :

```
    pane1.setBackground(Color.gray);
    m1 = new JLabel("Message from Sender...");
    pane1.add(m1);
```

Your best layout is as mentioned before GridBagLayout. [Check out this tutorial](http://blue-walrus.com/2011/12/gridbaglayout-tutorial/) .

You should have set GridBagLayout like this (filling the horizontal) :

```
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = y;


bottom.add(sender, gbc);
```

Then declare an integer field **y** and constraints object like this :

```
private int y = 0;
private GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
```

Then iterate y everytime you add a panel in your **actionPerformed(..)** method.

```
        gbc.gridy = y++;
        add(pane1, gbc);
```